# NoSuchMethodError: libcore.io.IoUtils.closeQuietly when using URLConnection

Tags: android, inputstream, urlconnection

I get `NoSuchMethodError: libcore.io.IoUtils.closeQuietly` when I use `URLConnection`on android 2.3.x

I use URLConnection to save file locally and use cache.

My app should run on android 2.3.x but compiled with API17 because of some AndroidManifest.xml defs.

I use JRE7. Maybe downgrading to JRE6 would help?

Any what causes it or how to solve it?

My code:

```
    public synchronized boolean saveFileLocally(String strUrl, String fileName) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (strUrl == null || fileName == null)
        return res;

    URL url = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(strUrl);
        URLConnection connection;
        connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.connect();
        input = connection.getInputStream(); // HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION

        byte[] buffer = getTempBitmapStorage();
        output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        res = true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (output != null) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Logcat:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: libcore.io.IoUtils.closeQuietly
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.closeSocketAndStreams(HttpConnection.java:136)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.release(HttpEngine.java:517)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:181)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
        at com.aa.android.utilslib.web.WebHelper.saveFileLocally(WebHelper.java:632)
        at com.bb.android.GCMIntentService.handleReceivedData(GCMIntentService.java:155)
        at com.bb.android.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:81)
        at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: It looks like "libcore.io.IoUtils" is missing - may be not aviable in android 2.3.x - have you ensured that its aviable? may be an manual import fix it?

Comment: closeQuietly procedure is missing. I guess it's not avilable on 2.3.x - but what can I do about it? I don't use it directly.
libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream use it...

Comment: I suggest to include the latest libcore library so you can be sure nothing is missing.( backwardcompatibility is allays pain.)

Answer (score 2):

See your error in locat and go to this link [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.3.1_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/HttpConnection.java):

```
public void closeSocketAndStreams() {
    IoUtils.closeQuietly(sslOutputStream);
    IoUtils.closeQuietly(sslInputStream);
    IoUtils.closeQuietly(sslSocket);
    IoUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
    IoUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    IoUtils.closeQuietly(socket);
}
```

line 136 is: IoUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);

We can see this method call IoUtils.closeQuietly with a **InputStream** parameter.

But when you see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.3.1_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/IoUtils.java) to view  IoUtils class

You can not find **closeQuietly** with a **InputStream** parameter. So, I think this is the cause of error. You should find another library or under version.

My english is not good.  I'm sorry for the inconvenience caused to you

Comment: I may be wrong here, but `InputStream` implements `Closeable`, which _is_ an `AutoCloseable` and `IoUtils.closeQuitely(AutoCloseable)` does exist.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting HttpsURLConnectionImpl to call IoUtils.closeQuietly? Are you including an external version of the HttpResponseCache library and building that from source by any chance? If so, that might be what's causing your problem (you're supposed to include it as a jar).

Just for curiosity's sake, if you compare the source for Gingerbread vs. say, 4.3 at

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/gingerbread/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/IoUtils.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.3_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/IoUtils.java

you will see that Gingerbread is missing the implementation of closeQuietly(Socket). But whatever version of HttpsURLConnectionImpl you're using is expecting a different version of IoUtils, which might come from the same place that particular HttpsURLConnectionImpl is coming from.